# Tracking changing values over time SQL database structure

Tags: sql-server, logging

I am building an application that displays values for the properties of various objects which change over time. As it stands, a table for a given object contains rows for instances of that object, containing the values representing the current state of its various properties. Each time the value of a property changes, the corresponding row is updated to reflect the new values.

However, I would like to capture historical data for the purposes of historical analysis.

My current plan is to create a log table for each of the existing 'current value' tables, adding a row to the corresponding log table any time a row is changed in the current value table. This would create flat tables of historical data, which have the potential to grow quite large over time.

I'm really just wondering if there is a best practice here that is different from this method of logging.

Comment: Do you use SQL2016 ?

Comment: It is a possibility; currently using 2014

Comment: SQL2016 comes with [temporal tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935015.aspx)(<> temporary tables / #localtemp / ##globaltemp). Also, depending on some specific requirements I would use: INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE with OUTPUT...INTO AuditTable clause, triggers, CHANGE TRACKING, CHANGE DATA CAPTURE, SQL Audit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have decided to use a trigger to insert rows into a log table for updates, inserts, and deletes on the table which contains values for which I need to keep an historical record.